# 複数のデザインを数ヶ月に一度のサイクルで回した際のSEOの懸念

Tags: javascript, html, css

自社の社長がコーポレートサイトのデザインを複数人に作成させ、それを数ヶ月ペースで回して使っていきたいと言っているのですが、これはSEO的に悪いのでしょうか？
ちなみにドメインは同じで、内容は違います。

Comment: 技術的にこれという解決方法としての解答があるわけではなく、ビジネス的なマーケティング戦略の一種の話ではないかと思います。このサイトの話題としては適合しないかもしれません。ちなみに、商品のランディングページについては、[ABテストで最適化を積み重ねていくのでフルに変更するのは得策ではない](https://netshop.impress.co.jp/node/8526)という話もありますが、コーポレートサイトの場合はどうかわかりません。

Comment: なるほど..LPだとそう言う話もあるのですね。ちなみに今回のケースですと、社長はweb関連にはほぼ無知であり、検索順位は上にしたい、と仰っています。ですが、いろんな人にデザインしてもらったので気分転換なような感じで回していきたいとのことなのです...もちろん各デザインの内容により、seo的に良い、悪いがあると思うので変更した際変動はあるのかと思いますが、サイト全体を何度も変更することによるSEO観点でのデメリットというのは一概にあるとは言えない感じなのでしょうか..